# Reset Object To Initial State Python

Tags: python, oop, constructor, reset, simplify

I am looking for a pointer on an appropriate way of resetting an object (planning code currently). What I currently have thought of is below. The only problem is that there are many other attributes that are defined in other methods that don't get deleted when I recall init. That isn't a problem for the way I structured my object (all the attributes not defined in init are always recalculated when simulation method is run). But, I don't feel like it's clean - I would prefer to do a full reset to the initialization state and not have any attributes defined outside of init.

```
class foo:

        def __init__(self, formaat):
                self.format == formaat
                # process format below:
                if formaat == one:
                        self.one = 1
                if formaat == two:
                        self.two = 2
                # ... other parameter imports below - dependent on the value of self.one/self.two

        def reset(self, formaat):
                self.__init__(formaat)

        def simulate(self):
                self.reset(self.format)
                print("doing stuff")
```

One thing I tried is having a method to copy itself. Although I think there is literally no difference between doing this and making a copy of the object in the run script and reassigning it.

```
class foo:

    def __init__(self, formaat):
                self.format = formaat
                # process format below:
                if formaat == one:
                        self.one = 1
                if formaat == two:
                        self.two = 2
                # ... other parameter imports below

    def copymyself(self):
        self.copy = copy.deepcopy(foo(self.format)) 

    def simulate(self):
        print("doing stuff")
```

Ideally I want to have the simulate method reset itself at the start every time. In the example code above I would have to do the following run script.

```
a = foo()
# loop the code below
a.copymyself()
a.simulate()
a = a.copy
```

I much rather prefer to have a single line - a.simulate() like in the case with the reset method.

Comment: Use a class to define a template for the "clean" initial object. Everytime you need to clean the object, just make a new instance of the class, and use the new object instead. That is how you should be using your classes and objects. Unless there is a very special requirement (like not instantiating more than one very heavy object; but as you are cleaning it, this does not look to apply here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every new run deserves a new (clean) object.

Comment: While very short, this is actually the right answer, and seen from another angle, it is a very concise one.